# List/set conversion goes wrong, why?

Tags: python

This code:

```
testset = list(set(child).union(pot_deck))
```

used to work, making `testset` a list that's a union of two lists `child` and `pot_deck`. I changed something seemingly unrelated in the code and now this comes out with a
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

I tried

```
testset = list(set(child).union(set(pot_deck)))
```

too, but with the same result.

Comment: does `child` or `pot_deck` contain lists in them? usually the unhashable error comes up when you try to have an element of the set be invalid to put in a set.

Comment: Print `child` and `pot_deck`. It looks like at least one of these has a list as a member.

Comment: Thank you. You're both right. Somehow it became a list on the way. I'll need to work on the code some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure not to have a list in any of the list you want to cast to a set. Lists are not hashable and hence can not be an element of a set.

Answer (score 0):

Lists with simple primitive values should be hashable, at least they are in Python 3.8 :

```
In [5]: child = [1]

In [6]: pot_deck = [2]

In [7]: testset = list(set(child).union(pot_deck))
   ...:

In [8]: testset
Out[8]: [1, 2]
```

However, if you have a list of lists, you'll get:

```
In [9]: child = [[1]]

In [10]: testset = list(set(child).union(pot_deck))
    ...:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-52828817787d> in <module>
----> 1 testset = list(set(child).union(pot_deck))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

So I assume that's what happened. You can print out the contents in `child` and `post_deck` and find out.